# Are multiple sources in nsswitch.conf merged for getpwent?

Tags: c, posix, glibc, libc, nss

Say I made a custom nss module called `foo` which defines abides by the required API:

```
#include <nss.h>

enum nss_status _nss_foo_getpwnam(const char *name, struct passwd *result, char *buf, size_t buflen, int *errnop);
enum nss_status _nss_foo_getpwuid(uid_t uid, struct passwd *result, char *buf, size_t buflen, int *errnop);
enum nss_status _nss_foo_setpwent(void);
enum nss_status _nss_foo_getpwent(struct passwd *result, char *buf, size_t buflen, int *errnop);
enum nss_status _nss_foo_endpwent(void);
```

Assuming I have my nsswitch.conf setup like so:

```
passwd: foo files
```

It is clear from the standard that `getpwnam()` for user `bar` would first call my `_nss_foo_getpwnam()` and then if that returns `NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND`, check `/etc/passwd`. However, the standard and behavior for `[set|get|end]pwent()` is a bit less clear to me. If I understand `man 5 nsswitch.conf` correctly, it sounds like this would first call my `_nss_foo_setpwent()` and if that returned `NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS` then it would only enumerate users from my module (because by default the action for success is to "immediately return" according to the man page). Is this interpretation correct?

Ideally, I'd like this use my module first and fallback approach for `getpwnam`/`getpwuid`, but for enuemrating users, I really need to merge the enumeration between all sources. Is there a way to accomplish this that isn't a total hack (the best I can think of is to manually read and parse `/etc/passwd` myself, because I obviously can't use `setpwent()`, because that would recursively invoke my `foo` module)?

Digging into the libc source, I discovered `ACTION=merge`, which seems to do what I want for `setpwent()` and friends. However, it seems like from the glibc >=2.24 man page for nsswitch.conf that this isn't supported for `getgrent()` and friends. Does this mean I'm stuck with a hacky solution for groups (like parsing `/etc/groups` myself)?